# Extension for automatic structuring of methods

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've got a fairly big class where I take a DF as input and store stats about said DF in a instance variable dictionary. For each separate stat I have several methods (for example, getting the data from the DF, calculating the stat and an add method used for `__add__`). Is there an extension that'll automatically order methods based either on alphabetical order or something else?

Comment: `DF` is a very well know acronym. What is this `something else`? I want this you want that. Write a python script to do the sorting of your Python code according to your own rules, or write an extension to do it on the current selection. It is all very language dependent so there is no universal method, you have to parse the file to know what a function is and what its name is and where it begins and ends

Comment: At present, python extensions do not provide relevant functions. I have submitted relevant function requests in [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/20154) for you

Comment: why even comment if you're gonna say something as un-helpful as that, @rioV8

Comment: Amazing, hopefully someone makes something! @MingJie-MSFT

Comment: YOU can be that someone that makes the feature

Comment: I didn't ask for mental support in making a functionality though, did I? @rioV8

Comment: I don't give mental support, never, if you want a feature and it is not implemented yet the best solution is to implement it yourself, otherwise you have to wait a LONG time until some other soul wants it and also is not waiting till another is implementing it, and most of the time the implementation is not what you want, the feature you want is implemented in a few hours in an extension, so what keeps you waiting

Comment: @rioV8 my question specifically is wether such functionality exists? Nowhere am I asking anyone else to implement it for me, I’m asking if someone already has done so. Your comment is rude, and frankly stupid.

Comment: It is not stupid it is intelligent comment based on your question/comment, if you **have** done the search and not found an implementation you write it yourself, you write a comment (4) where you wait till somebody will make it so your previous comment is false, and you could have written it yourself 5 times in the last 2 days

Comment: @rioV8 WTF is wrong with you? Why do you feel the need to comment things that are this unhelpful online? Are you ok? This is NOT normal behavior. Take a look in the mirror.

Comment: I can't take a look in the mirror, I don't have a reflection. I have plenty of time during daylight, during night time I have other business. As if your comments are helpful: **`I want this, who will write it for me`** I comment that you could write it yourself faster

Answer (score 0):

According to [github](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3575), although I'm not sure what df is in your article, you can sort the method of your python file in the outline.

[image]

At present, it provides three sorting methods: **Position**, **Name** and **Category**.